# Windows 10 Upgrade 32-bit to 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-activation, windows-10-upgrade

So, Windows 10 Upgrade is being rolled out worldwide, and I have 'reserved' my upgrade.

Currently my computer is running Windows 7 Pro 32-bit. I'm planning to 'upgrade' it to Windows 10 64-bit (via fresh install, of course).

After reading many references, these will be the steps I'll do:

1. Let the "Get Windows 10" app upgrade my OS to Windows 10 32-bit
2. Note the activation key
3. Download the Installation Media for Windows 10, but choosing 64-bit instead
4. Perform a clean install
5. Reactivate using the activation key in Step #2

(Of course I'll backup my data first.)

However, I still have some questions:

1. On Windows 7, the activation key does not differ between 32- or 64-bit versions. Is it still so with Windows 10?
2. Will I be able to download a different architecture on Step #3?
3. Is there anything I need to prepare beforehand?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You do understand that the second step does not happen right?  You don't have a Windows 10 product key, you won't have, activation after the first upgrade will happen automatically.

Comment: @Ramhound ah, I misread the references there. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing with the free Windows 10 upgrade is that your hardware is whitelisted, and a generic key used (not like the Windows 8.1 upgrade where you get a unique key). This means that you can let the `Get Windows 10` app upgrade you, then reinstall Windows using a 64bit ISO.

Unfortunately, this also means that since no one except Microsoft themselves knows which hardware is used to fingerprint the PC, if one part breaks, you can safely assume you have to go back to Windows 7 and upgrade once more.

Comment: @Ramhound I did indeed, and got the message that the key is generic and is blocked from activation, yet is assigned to *every* Windows 10 (Upgrade) Pro PC

Comment: I know that.  I am trying to get my head around it.  The EULA literally says something else.  Anyways this is not on topic.  Great answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So, I will be able to fresh install the 64-bit WIndows without any problems, as long as I first go the upgrade process, right? Thanks! I'll mark your answer.

Comment: @pepoluan - Provided you start the upgrade from within Windows, you can actually select not to keep anything, and you end up with exactly what a "clean install" does.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a direct clean install with windows 10 and use the windows 7/8 key to activate it.you can download the iso from here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10iso